# The bottom part of my menu's items are cutted on the right side from items them selves

Tags: c#, asp.net, menu, menuitem, display

I want to make a menu sample in asp.net and items are diplayed as I want, the only problem is that the bottom side of each item is cutted and displayed next to items them selves

[image]

As you can see in the picture, when I hover on the item, on the right side is the bottom of the item I hover on, and what is fun about this, on the right side , bottoms are diplayed in exacly the same order as my items are. Does somebody know what the problem might be ? Thank you very much in advance.
Here is my sample code

```
 <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DocumentSolution.master.cs" Inherits="Document_Solution.DocumentSolution" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

          <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" DynamicHoverStyle-Font-Names="Menu1" runat="server" CssClass="menu" Orientation="Horizontal" OnMenuItemClick="Menu1_MenuItemClick" BackColor="#F7F6F3" DynamicHorizontalOffset="2" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="2.0em" ForeColor="#7C6F57" StaticSubMenuIndent="50px">
            <DynamicHoverStyle ForeColor="White" />
            <DynamicMenuStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" />
            <DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" />
            <Items>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Indstillinger" Value="Setup" NavigateUrl="~/Settings.aspx" Target="Blank"></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Hent fra Mail" Value="Mails"></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Indscan billag" Value="ScenDocuments"></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Log af" Value="LogOut" ></asp:MenuItem>
            </Items>
            <StaticHoverStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" ForeColor="White" />
            <StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="20px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
            <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" />
            <StaticItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("Text") %>
            </StaticItemTemplate>
        </asp:Menu>

    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">


        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    </div>

    </div>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This looks like a styling problem. Do you have any css files?

Comment: Try checking the menu's and the item's height.

Comment: Tank you very much for help, your were right, it was styling problem, not with size, but the default "float:left" proprety for menu and menu items. So I added  my css file where I removed it with "clear: both;" and it worked.